# Vue method runs even if I change route, how to run method only if I am on a specific route/component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component, vue-cli-4

I am retrieving posts from a Wordpress API and on scroll I want to load more posts and it works. But whenever I click on a post to open another route when I scroll on the bottom the app makes a call to the API, it basically runs the `scroll()` method from the other component. I am using the vue-router and axios.

Home Component:

```
    <template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!--       Post         -->
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-4" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <div style="overflow: hidden">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" v-bind:src="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url" alt="Card image cap">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <router-link :to="{ path: '/article/' + post.slug, query: { id: post.id }, params: { title: post.slug }}">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title.rendered }}</h5>
                            </router-link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: "Home",
        data(){
            return {
                posts: [],
                errors: [],
                pagination: 2,
                totalPages: null
            }
        },

        // Fetches posts when the component is created.

        methods: {
            getPosts() {
                axios.get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed')
                    .then(response => {
                        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                        this.posts = response.data;
                        this.totalPages = response.headers['x-wp-totalpages'];
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    });
            },

            scroll () {
                window.onscroll = () => {
                    let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

                    if (bottomOfWindow) {
                        if(this.pagination <= this.totalPages) {
                            axios.get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&&page=' + this.pagination)
                                .then(response => {
                                    this.posts = this.posts.concat(response.data);
                                    this.pagination = this.pagination + 1;
                                });
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.getPosts();
        },

        mounted() {
            this.scroll();
        }

    }


</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    h1{
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .card-body{
        a{
            color: #00b6f1;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

            &:hover{
                color: #62d4f9;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

Single post component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center mt-5 mb-5">
                    <img class="img-fluid" :src="featuredImage" alt="Card image cap">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 content">
                    <p v-html="content">{{ content }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";


    export default {
        name: "Single",
        data(){
            return {
                post: {},
                featuredImage: null,
                errors: [],
                title: null,
                content: null,
            }
        },

        methods:{
            getPost() {
                axios.get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'+this.$route.query.id+'?_embed')
                    .then(response => {
                        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                        this.post = response.data;
                        this.featuredImage = response.data._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url;
                        this.title = response.data.title.rendered;
                        this.content = response.data.content.rendered;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
            },
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.getPost();
        },
    }

</script>

<style lang="scss">
    .content{
        img, iframe{
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        iframe{
            height: 300px;
        }

        p{
            color: #767676;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 24px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        h2{
            color: black;
        }

        a {
            color: #00b6f1;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

            &:hover{
                color: #62d4f9;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I can’t see if that method is placed directly on the view or in an external component file. Maybe, you can just move it from the current position to another (outside the single post view file or in a component you don’t import there). Basically the `scroll()` method shouldn’t be present in the single post view.

Comment: Hello, the scroll method is inside the home view. When I go to the single post view where I don't use or mount the scroll method it still runs. Moreover, when I go directly to the single post view the scroll method doesn't run but when I go to the home view and back to the single post view the scroll methods runs again everywhere

Comment: I added better screenshots from both components

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , The question should contain the code, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `Home.vue`:

```
beforeDestroy() {
  this.scroll = null
  delete this.scroll
}
```

It happens because, when changing route, the `scroll()` method is still mounted. This should prevent it from being loaded elsewhere than in `Home.vue`.

Comment: Thanks, the hook works but the the function inside doesn't. It still runs on other views. Is there a way to unmount the function?

Comment: I believe there is something to do with the `window.onscroll` function. I tried the `scroll()` function  with `console.log` and it deleted the function successfully when I changed route.

Comment: Try with my update. It should work, but if it doesn’t, try calling `destroyed` instead of `beforeDestroy`. More on Vue.js lifecycle: https://scotch.io/tutorials/demystifying-vue-lifecycle-methods

Comment: tried it, didn't work. But I figured out a different way, like this: `destroyed() {
            window.onscroll = null;
        }` and works. I'm not sure if this is right but works, thank again

Comment: Maybe it treats `scroll` as a reserved word for `windows.scroll`, as you imagined.

Comment: It's because you have bound an anonymous function to the global `window.scroll` event. As you're using a single page app, it is still bound even if the component is not in scope anymore because the page is not refreshed. To remove it, you indeed need to set `window.scroll` to null. Deleting `this.scroll` has no effect because it is not bound to window.scroll, but the anonymous function still is.